# PHP script with form not sending the email

Tags: php, email

I am having some problems with php. Well, the code, when uploaded to the server and run in browser is working and the email is arriving, using this code below:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer();


$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->IsSMTP();
//$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';


$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';

$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPSecure = false;

$mail->SMTPAuth = false;

$mail->Username = "exemple@gmail.com";

$mail->Password = "password";    

$name = "catarina";
$email = "myEmail@hotmail.com";
$message = "test";

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);

$mail->addAddress('me@exemple.io');     

$mail->Subject = 'Contact Site';

$mail->Body = $message;


//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

The problem is, when I change this code a little to send with a form, the email never arrives:

**js:**

```
 function submitForm() {

      $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'email-action.php', data:$('#contact-form').serialize(), success: function(result){
            $('.submit').html('send');
     $('.send').removeClass('no-show');
      $('.send').removeClass('no-show-mobile');
        }});



   };
```

**html:**

```
 <form action="/" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="post" name="contactform" class="contact-form wow zoomIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s" id="contact-form">

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">

               <input placeholder="Name" class="input-field" name="name" required="" type="text">

             </div>

             <div class="col-md-12">
               <input placeholder="E-mail" class="input-field" name="email" required="" type="email"> 
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
           <textarea placeholder="Message" class="input-field" name="message"></textarea> 
           <input value="Send Message" class="input-send submit" type="submit" name="submit">
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-12 send no-show hidden-xs"><button class=" botao btn btn-sucess"><h4 class="">Message sent sucessfully! We will get in touch shortly.</h4></button></div>
         <div class="col-md-12 send no-show-mobile visible-xs"><button class=" botao btn btn-sucess"><h4 class="">Message sent sucessfully!</h4></button></div>

</form>
```

**php:**

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';


    $mail = new PHPMailer();


    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    //$mail->IsSMTP();

    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    $mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';

    $mail->Port = 25;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = false;

    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;

    $mail->Username = "exemple@gmail.com";

    $mail->Password = "password";

///this is the thing that change for one script to another
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
 /////   
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

    $mail->addAddress('me@exemple.io');     

    $mail->Subject = 'Contact Site';

    $mail->Body = $message;


    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
```

Comment: It says the forms action is pointing to /. (action="/") Is that the correct location of your PHP file?

Comment: check the values of `$name` `$email` `$message`, what did you get ?

Comment: @Brogan unfortunately that's not the error, but i will try to change the location a bit to see what happens, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mohammad i put an echo to see what this values were, but, for some reason, the echo does not appears at the page when i submit the mail

Comment: Did you change the action of the form? / sends the form to index.php or the root of the web server.

Comment: @Brogan in action i should put the name of the php file, isn`t it? 
I am really lost in php haha, sorry for the dummy question :/

Comment: This is an HTML issue, not really a PHP issue. It all depends on where the PHP file is located relative to the file that the form is located. If its the same directory, don't put the slash action="myfile.php", if its in a totally different directory, do action="/here/myfile.php".

Comment: i put it in the same folder as my html application, but i will give a better look to see if the error is there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your form is mysite.com/hello/form.php and your mail file is mysite.com/hello/mail.php use action="mail.php"

Comment: i put it there, just as you said, but still not working

Comment: please remove the action attribute from your form tag, no need for it because you are using ajax, also remove the onsubmit attribute, then change your js function to: $('#contact-form').submit(function(e){  e.preventDefault(); //your ajax function... });

Comment: @Mohammad i just did it but still nothing :/ many thanks 
even so :)

Comment: @Mohammad i put a console.log in sucess js function, and it appears, so it`s sending but no arriving in my email, don't know why

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira what response did you get from the php? "Message sent" or "Mailer Error.." ? if nothing please do `var_Dump($_POST)` in your php code

Comment: @Mohammad the echo don't appears at the page, don't know why, but the ajax function enters in the "sucess" at js code

Comment: ok but what is the result of `vara_dump()` ?

Comment: the result is that the page shows nothing, white page, not "message sent"or other stuff